# Detect exact color range of most spread color in a given image using OpenCv C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, numbers, standard-deviation

I am new to OpenCV and developing image processing program using opencv c++. I have a image with only defined color (ex - pink).

[image]

I get the RGB value of image to 3 separate arrays.If I consider R value array, I can get number set like bellow.If I consider that number set, there is a standard values and other numbers should have a close values to it. But there are some numbers which are highly deviated from that number and I want to remove them from number set.In the bellow number set should remove 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 57  and 243 , 255 , 255 .Finally I want to get color range of given color image.I want to get 166 - 170 range cluster .What is the best way to solve this?. Is there any simple way to solve this  using opencv? or have to develop algorithm?

0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 57 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 166 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 ,167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 167 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 168 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 169 , 170 , 170 ,170 , 243 , 255 ,  255

Here is my

```
        Mat image;
        image = imread("saved.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        const int SIZE = image.rows*image.cols;
        int bValue[SIZE];
        int gValue[SIZE];
        int rValue[SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=1;i <= image.rows; i++){
            for(int j=1;j <= image.cols; j++){
                int b = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0];
                int g = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1];
                int r = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2];

                bValue[index]= b ;
                gValue[index]= g ;
                rValue[index]= r ;
                index++;                    
            }                
        }
        sort(bValue,bValue+SIZE);
        sort(gValue,gValue+SIZE);
        sort(rValue,rValue+SIZE);
```

Comment: You have to figure out **exactly** what you want to do first.  Sounds like you need to get some summary statistics on your sample (e.g. mean, standard deviation) and then use them to do the elimination.

Comment: @AnonMail , I want to remove only deviated numbers from my data set.I want to get only static range( ex - 166 to 170)

Comment: If you know the removal criteria, then write a function and use `copy_if` or `remove_if` C++ algorithm to eliminate them.  See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm for documentation on algorithms.

Comment: I don't know removal criteria.because data set is change time to time

Comment: That's why I mentioned getting summary statistics first.  Given those, you can adjust your removal criteria based on the data set (e.g. anything over two standard deviations from the mean).

Comment: Thanks @AnonMail, I will try forthat

Comment: If you define the upper and lower bound with some statistics, you can use "cv::inRange". You'll probably get better result using HSV color space

Comment: Thanks for the helping me.I want to find upper and lower bound to apply for inRange function.But I can't find bound.because it change when i change the image

Comment: how did you get the number set ? could you share the code ?

Comment: @sturkmen I edited my question and put the code in queastion.

Comment: still i wonder how did you get 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 57 etc. did you get the values with the source image you give?

Comment: Image is not pained image.I crop that image from camera view and saved it.that value com from that saved image.that is why values are changing.